# Constructing an object using a given file

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use a constructor to create an object from a file, the file should contain (on the first line) an Int in String format which is meant to be the number of rows for the MD Array and then has a space followed by another Int in String format. I'm trying to "grab" these two Strings, parse them into an int and then instantiate the MD Array by using these two ints I've "grabbed." I'm just not quite sure where I'm going wrong, as I've just begun using File I/O in my coding. Here's my code.

```
public SeatingChart(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, DataFormatException, IOException
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    String rowStr = "";
    String colStr = "";

    if (scan.hasNext())
    {
        rowStr = scan.next();
        colStr = scan.next();
    }

    rows = Integer.parseInt(rowStr);
    columns = Integer.parseInt(colStr);

    seats = new Student[rows][columns];

    scan.close();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: `Scanner.nextInt()`?

Comment: @CardinalSystem it isn't an int when it's in the file, or at least not to my knowledge.

Comment: Well how do you know you are going wrong?

Comment: @immibis there is a jar file that was given to my class that I am supposed to put the file into and everytime I put in the file, it gets an error.

Comment: @JamwadAmadeusDixon I went to drive to the store today because I needed to get some milk because I used up the last of the milk making creamy scrambled eggs but the car crashed, what did I do wrong?

Comment: @immibis I'm gonna go ahead an say that it wasn't wrong that you used up the last of the milk, but rather that when you went to get new milk that you crashed the car.

Comment: @JamwadAmadeusDixon Okay! But if you want to tell *how* I went wrong you want to know about the crash itself, and what I was doing before I crashed. Sometimes you don't need both - if I took fast-acting sleeping pills then you know what happened; If I got hit by a car running a red light then it doesn't matter what *I* was doing - but usually both of those are very helpful for diagnosing the problem. In this question I don't know what actually happened when you ran the program, except that "it gets an error" - which is like saying "the car crashed".

Comment: @immibis I figured out I'm getting a "NoSuchElementException." I've looked it up, but I'm not quite sure how exactly to go about fixing it. Should I add a break after the two scan.nexts in the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, You want to grab two numbers, in string format, separated by a space. 
I would grab the entire line then trim the string which ensures there is no space before or after the numbers I need. Then split them based on space.

Look at this simplified step by step example. This example will create a file called numbers.txt then put in it string "5 2". Then the file will be read and taken apart to get the numbers.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;

PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter("numbers.txt", "UTF-8");
fileWriter.println("5 2");
fileWriter.close();
File file = new File("numbers.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
String numbersString;
if (input.hasNextLine()) numbersString = input.nextLine();

// Trim the string to ensure you have what you need.
numbersString = numbersString.trim();

// Split both numbers according to the space within them.
String[] numsArray = numbersString.split("\\s+");

// Get your numbers. 
int row = Integer.valueOf(numsArray[0]);
int col = Integer.valueOf(numsArray[1]);
```